# I am looking for the expected output from the current output below in excel

Tags: excel

How to change column headers as row indexes

I am looking for the expected output from the current output below in excel.

output:

```
Column_A        Column_B        Column_C        Column_D
A               B                  C            D
A               B                  C            D
A               B                  C            D
A               B                  C            D
A               B                  C            D
A               B                  C            D
```

output should be:

```
Column A    A
Column A    A
Column A    A
Column A    A
Column A    A
Column A    A
    
Column_B    B
Column_B    B
Column_B    B
Column_B    B
Column_B    B
Column_B    B

Column_C    C
Column_C    C
Column_C    C
Column_C    C
Column_C    C
Column_C    C

Column_D    D
Column_D    D
Column_D    D
Column_D    D
Column_D    D
Column_D    D
```

Comment: What have you tried and where have you run into problems? This would seem to be a slightly modified `unpivot` operation of which there are numerous examples on this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(B1="A";"Column A";IF(B1="B";"Column B";IF(B1="C";"Column C";IF(B1="D";"Column D"))))
```

This formula calculates the row index, based on the values "A", "B", "C" and "D" in column B (start at B1 and drag down).